# Gradle cannot handle generated code changes

Tags: android, gradle, android-databinding

My setup:

- Android Gradle Plugin 3.5.0
- Gradle to 5.5.1
- 100+ Gradle modules
- lot of generated code (mostly Dagger + data binding)

When I checkout a branch which causes changes in generated code then usually I have to wipe out whole .gradle/caches directory to make the build succeed. Otherwise gradle build system tries to resolve some old generated code.

`clean` and `cleanBuildCache` don't help. Also a side note: so far I've been a happy user but since we updated tools to these versions then build caching stopped working properly. Any tips?

EDIT: Please note that not every change in generated code breaks the cache. It's nondeterministic for me so far.

Comment: You should find a way to share your `buildCache`. When you're having CVS, it's sometimes headache to handle huge project having lots of modules. Solution is available here : https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_cache.html#sec:build_cache_configure

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm a java developer and am not familiar with the Android plugin

The clean task won't remove entries from the build cache. The cache key is derived from the task inputs and outputs. If you haven't declared all of the task inputs correctly then the cache key won't be correct

If (for example) your "generate" task needs a template, some xml and a system property to generate the sources you will need to declare all three (template, xml and syspop) as task inputs to the "generate" task. Any output directory(s) will obviously need to be declared as a task output.

The last thing to consider is that the "generate" task is correctly wired into Gradle's [DAG](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph). Eg the "compileJava" task should "dependsOn" your "generate" task (or whatever the android equivalent task is)

Comment: I am sure that all our generated code goes to the "build" dir. We don't have any custom tools for code generation - we only use latest stable versions of open source libraries used by thousands of devs.

Comment: I'd be concentrating my efforts on making sure that all task inputs and outputs are declared for the code generation task. Ultimately these define the cache key